# how do i use react router in if/else condition in a function called by button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const handleStartClick = () => {
    const email = localStorage.getItem('email')
    if (email !== null && email.length !== 0) {
      alert('not empty!')
    } else {
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/EmailInput" element={<EmailInput />}/>
        </Routes>
    }
  }
```

I want to use router in else condition to route to a different component.
The function `handleStartClick` is called after button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

---

If you want to trigger navigation from a callback:

1. Define your route with your other routes, giving it a path
2. Navigate to that path with the `navigate` function returned by the [`useNavigate` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)

---

If you want to show a different component in a given context, without it being a whole new route, then set a state instead. Determine which component to show in the render function.

Comment: Sir i just want to know how do i open another component in else condition

Comment: @deoxzy — As per the first paragraph of this answer: Not with anything like the approach you are attempt. As per the rest of the answer: There are two approaches you could take there.

Comment: using the hook useNaviagte worked. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is how we use if-else in jsx

```
 return (<Routes>
  {(email !== null && email.length !== 0)&&alert("not empty!") ||  <Route path="/EmailInput" element={<EmailInput />}/> }

</Routes>)
```